# Python: How may I multiply all items in a list without using any prebuilt function?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I know that I should be using a for loop, but I can´t figure out how exactly.

```
def product_list(list):
    for item in list:
```

I´ve search about this isse, but i´ve found replies that involves map() and lambda. How may I do it with a loop?

Comment: Say your list is [1,2,3], do you want to compute 1*2*3? Or multiply all of them with, say, 5, to get [5,10,15]?

Comment: why don't you like a lambda with reduce?

Comment: I want to multiply each item like 1*2*3. I´m just starting with python and want to bettrer understand the for loop.

Answer (score 4):

Use a temporary variable, and multiply each item to it:

```
def product_list(my_list):  # Don't use `list` as variable name
    product = 1
    for item in my_list:
        product *= item
    return product
```

A better way would be to use [`reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) with [`operator.mul`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.mul):

```
import operator

def product_list(my_list):
    return reduce(operator.mul, my_list, 1)
```

Comment: It's compound operator. Same as : `product = product * item`.

Comment: That means, product = product * item